# Permission denied within mounted volume inside Podman container

Tags: permissions, volume, persistent-volumes, podman

I am starting to learn about containers using `podman` that came with RHEL8.1 (which AFAIK can be used in place of `docker`), and have the following baby `Dockerfile` as a learning exercise:

```
# Use Alpine Linux base image
FROM alpine:latest

# Install pacakges
RUN apk --no-cache add bash gcc make

# Make a directory for source code
RUN mkdir /src_dir

# Set working directory to the same directory
WORKDIR /src_dir

# Set this directory as a volume
VOLUME [ "/src_dir" ]
```

As you can see, I've installed the most basic `gcc` and `make` into this container with the goal of mounting a set of source files on my container host into the `/src_dir` directory within the container.

I next build the container image in the host directory containing the `Dockerfile`:

```
podman build -t my_image .
```

I then start the container with this command

```
podman run -it -v /host/foobar:/src_dir /bin/bash
```

Where `/host/foobar/` on my host is an arbitrary directory containing some arbitrary source code, all of which my local user on the host has full read/write access to. For example, there is one file `/host/foobar/test.c`. This then brings me to a `bash` prompt inside the container. I can see that I'm at the correct place because:

```
bash-5.0# pwd
/src_dir
```

However, I have absolutely no read/write access to `/src_dir`. Both `ls -lh` and `cat test.c` gave me permission denied errors. If I change to the root directory (or any other directory) of the container, I can see and access other things. Strangely, if I run `ls -lh /` I can see `/src_dir` as being owned by `root:root`, so I don't understand why as the container's root user I can't access anything in it.

I also tried `podman inspect [container ID]`, and in the output I can see:

```
...
"Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Name": "",
                "Source": "/host/foobar",
                "Destination": "/src_dir",
                "Driver": "",
                "Mode": "",
                "Options": [
                    "rbind"
                ],
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ]
...
```

Which suggests that there *is* read/write permission?

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious as a beginner, but what do I have to do so that I can run the `gcc` and `make` inside this container on the source files mounted in `/src_dir` *so that the container essentially acts as a complete development environment*?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Thanks to the people [here](https://old.reddit.com/r/podman/comments/fww87v/permission_denied_within_mounted_volume_inside/), the solution is quite simple (but not obvious):

My GNU/Linux container host has SELinux activated, and that's why I was having permissions problems. The solution is to simply append a `:z` to the `podman run` volume argument so that this:

`podman run -it -v /host/foobar:/src_dir /bin/bash`

becomes this:

`podman run -it -v /host/foobar:/src_dir:z /bin/bash`

That's it.

Comment: I 've spent so many hours trying to understand the cause of a similar error on my rpi4 running fedora iot, experimenting with linuxserver.io containers. Finally I understood the problem well enough that I was able to find this answer! Thank you! The following red hat post appears to have some more information
https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/user-namespaces-selinux-rootless-containers

Comment: The `:z` flag is not supported in Mac OS. Any suggestions on a fix for that host env?

Comment: @Jeremy but MacOS also doesn't run SELinux, does it? `:z` helps when the error is SELinux related, you likely have a different problem.